# Convex Hull of a Partial Minkowski Sum

Tags: euclidean-geometry, computational-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $A$ and $B$ be polygons in the plane, each with $n$ vertices.
Their Minkowski sum is defined as:
$$A + B = \{a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B \}$$
and has the property:
$$
|\text{Conv}(A+B)| \leq 2n
$$
where $|...| $ denotes the number of vertices in a set.

If we define a *partial Minkowski sum* as:
$$A \otimes B = \{a + b \mid (a, b) \in C, C \subset A \times B \}$$
does the following property hold?
$$
|\text{Conv}(A \otimes B)| \leq 2n
$$

I'm having difficulty adapting the standard proof (in e.g. De Berg's Computational Geometry), as the partial sum can introduce new edges into $\text{Conv}(A \otimes B)$ which exist in neither $A$ nor $B$.  Ideally, I would like to generalize the result to multiple polygons.

In a related question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27040/a-variation-of-minkowski-sum this operation is dubbed a 'sumset along a graph' rather than a partial Minkowski sum.